# Understanding Hanh-Banach theorem in its normed vector space form.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

**Theorem:** Let $E$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, let $F$ be a vectorial subspace of E and let $\phi$ be a linear bounded operator over $F$, i.e, $\phi \in F^{*}$. Then, there exists a bounded linear operator $\phi_{1}$ over $E$, such that $\phi_{1}$ **extends** $\phi$ and also, $|| \phi_{1}||_{E^{*}}
=|| \phi||_{F^{*}}$

**Problem:** I can't imagine (geometrically) how does this extension works. If I got lots of bounded operators in a space $F$ floating around, then, I take one, lets say $\phi$ and well, since that operator was inside a subspace is natural(I think) to be able to take another bounded operator of bigger size from the bigger space $E$, lets say $\phi_{1}$, such that the new operator contains the operator from the smaller one.

The thing is I dont think that my interpretation of what is happening is correct. So, if you guys could help me imagine whats going on with the extensions I would really appreciate it.

Thanks so much. :)

Comment: $\phi_1$ extends $\phi$ means that the restriction of $\phi_1$ to $F$ is $\phi$.

Comment: Linear bounded **operator** usually means it maps $F$ into some other normed space, but $F^*$ usually denotes the space of bounded linear **functionals**, mapping $F$ into $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  The Hahn-Banach theorem is true for **functionals** but not in general for **operators**.

Comment: the Hahn-Banach theorem, in it full form, is based in the Zorn's lemma, so you only need to imagine the Zorn's lemma. More than "geometry" you need other kind of imagination.

Comment: (I had a mistake in my previous comment, so it was deleted and replaced by this one) I must add that, as already said by @NateEldredge, the word "operator" generally is reserved to functions of the form $f:A→A$, but this is not the case for linear functionals (and the Hahn-Banach theorem is just about linear functionals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $E=\Bbb R^3$ and $F=\Bbb R^2\times \{0\}$ and $\phi(x,y,0)=2x+y.$  Any extension of $\phi$ to $\phi'\in E^*$ must satisfy $\phi'(x,y,z)=2x+y+kz$ for some constant $k,$ but the only extension without a larger norm is $\phi_1(x,y,z)=2x+y.$

Normed vector spaces appear in analysis. E.g. $C[0,1],$ the set of continuous $f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R,$ with $\|f\|=\max \{|f(x)|: x\in [0,1]\},$ which is infinite-dimensional. In infinite dimensions it is possible that there may be more than one choice for $\phi_1.$

Two useful corollaries of Hahn-Banach: (1). For any $x\in E$ there exists $f\in E^*$ with $f(x)=\|x\|$ and $\|f\|=1$...(2). If $x\in E\setminus \overline F$ there exists $f\in E^*$ with $f(x)\ne 0$ and $\{f(y): y\in F\}=\{0\}.$